# Node JS Error: (Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client)

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js

What I'm trying to do in my program is that I want to use both `res.send` and `render` at the same time with the same data. Because I have a Qt application that is able to receive the data from my Node JS. But it seems that I can't send and render the data on the webpage at the same time.

```
------SERVER.JS-------
app.use('/number',function(req, res){  // created an API which gets the MySQL data onto that certain web directory

db.query("SELECT * FROM qnumber",function(error,rows,fields){ //query the data with the function and its parameters

    if(value <= rows.length){    
       value++;
       const getNumber = rows[value].qNumberCount;
       const displayNumber = rows[value].qNumberCount;
       console.log('array: '+value +' = '+ getNumber);  

    res.render('index',{title: 'CIV Queueing System',getNumber});
    return res.send(displayNumber);

    }    
    else{
        console.log('Error in Query!');
        console.log(error); //display in the console the specific error
        }

    });

    });

------INDEX.HANDLEBARS-------
<html>
 <head>
 <style>

 body{background: burlywood;font-family: verdana;color: whitesmoke;padding: 30px;}
  h1{font-size: 48px; text-transform: uppercase; letter-spacing: 2px; text-align: center; color: cornflowerblue;}
  p{font-size: 16px;text-align: center;}
 </style>
 <h1>Queue Counts</h1><br>
 </head>
 <body class="text-center"> 

 {{this.getNumber}} 

 </body>
 <script src="/reload/reload.js"></script>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't call both `res.render()` and `res.send()` for the same request.  Pick one of the other, not both.  You only get to send one response for each http request.

You don't explain what you're trying to accomplish by sending both.  If you are sending an HTML page, then you would pass the data you want to `res.render()` and the template you are using would do something useful with that data such as render it into HTML or put it into a Javascript variable in the rendered page so your scripts in the page can access it on the client-side.

If you're just trying to send a single value back as the response (and no HTML page), then get rid of the `res.render()` and the `res.send()` and use `res.json()` and pass a Javascript object with your data in it to `res.json()`.

Answer (score 0):

Error comes from below code

```
 res.render('index',{title: 'CIV Queueing System',getNumber});
 return res.send(displayNumber);
```

you are sending multiple time response to same request .

you can send response only once to request .

you can pass variable `displayNumber` in side `res.render()`

```
 res.render('index',{title:'CIV Queueing System',
                     getNumber:getNumber,
                     displayNumber:displayNumber
                    });
```

or you can use  `res.locals` to pass data like :

```
res.locals.title='CIV Queueing System';
res.locals.getNumber=getNumber;
res.locals.displayNumber=displayNumber;
res.render('index');
```

and use it inside view